# show one div and hide others on button click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have four buttons and four `div`. Now, I want to show only one `div` at a time. It means, if I click the first button, only the first `div` should be visible and the others should be hidden.

I have searched a lot with no luck. Please help me. I have tried just to show as below:

**html**

```
<button  ng-click="showAbout();">About Page</button>
  <button ng-click="showhelp();">Help page</button>
  <button ng-click="showinfo();">Info Page</button>
  <button  ng-click="showref();">Refrence page</button>

  <div class="form-group" ng-show="showabout">
    <p>About page</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-show="showhelp" >
    <p>Help page</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-show="showinfo" >
    <p>Info</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-show="showref" >
    <p>Refrence</p>
  </div>
```

**js**

```
$scope.showabout = true;
$scope.showAbout = function () {
  $scope.showhelp = false;
  $scope.showinfo = false;
  $scope.showref = false;
};

$scope.showhelp = true;
$scope.showhelp = function () {
  $scope.showabout = false;
  $scope.showinfo = false;
  $scope.showref = false;
};

$scope.showinfo = true;
$scope.showinfo = function () {
  $scope.showabout = false;
  $scope.showhelp = false;
  $scope.showref = false;
};

$scope.showref = true;
$scope.showref = function () {
  $scope.showabout = false;
  $scope.showhelp = false;
  $scope.showinfo = false;
};
```

Comment: You are overwriting your booleans with functions, since you are assigning them to the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18972/)

```
   <button  ng-click="show = 1">About Page</button>
   <button  ng-click="show = 2">Help page</button>
   <button  ng-click="show = 3">Info Page</button>
   <button  ng-click="show = 4">Refrence page</button>

    <div class="form-group" ng-show="show==1" >
       <p>About page</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-show="show==2" >
       <p>Help page</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-show="show==3" >
       <p>Info</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-show="show==4" >
       <p>Refrence</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi..Thanks and what about the js changes?

Comment: hi..but nothing is happening on button clicks..:(

Comment: ohh...sorry..i didnt have changed in my js..now its working like a charm...thanks bro..:)

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like this is the perfect use case for ng-switch.

```
<div ng-switch on="visibleDiv">
  <div ng-switch-when="showhelp"><p>Help page</p></div>
  <div ng-switch-when="showinfo"><p>Infopage</p></div>
  <div ng-switch-when="showref"><p>Ref page</p></div>
  <div ng-switch-default><p>About page</p></div>
</div>
```

so, guessing you want the showabout div to be your default div, when you click on the button just change the visibleDiv variable to whatever div you want to be visible.

EDIT: here is a plunker. [JS FIDDLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/ri1QzmKtPyR5pJdKPsOF?p=preview)

Comment: can you pls edit my code..i am really cant understand as i just started.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
$scope.showabout = true;
            $scope.show==1 = function(){

                $scope.show==2 = false;
                 $scope.show==3 = false;
                  $scope.show==4 = false;
            };
               $scope.show==2 = true;
            $scope.show==2 = function(){

                $scope.show==1 = false;
                 $scope.show==3 = false;
                  $scope.show==4 = false;
            };
             $scope.show==3 = true;
            $scope.show==3 = function(){

                $scope.show==1 = false;
                 $scope.show==2 = false;
                  $scope.show==4 = false;
            };
             $scope.show==4 = true;
              $scope.show==4 = function(){

                $scope.show==1 = false;
                 $scope.show==2 = false;
                  $scope.show==3 = false;
            };
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/8gmdcb7w/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one

this is the controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.divShow = "div1"

  $scope.show = function(arg) {
    $scope.divShow = arg;
  }
});
```

and this is the view

```
<button ng-click="show('div1')">show div 1</button>
<button ng-click="show('div2')">show div 2</button>
<button ng-click="show('div3')">show div 3</button>
<button ng-click="show('div4')">show div 4</button>

<div ng-show="divShow == 'div1'">div 1</div>
<div ng-show="divShow == 'div2'">div 2</div>
<div ng-show="divShow == 'div3'">div 3</div>
<div ng-show="divShow == 'div4'">div 4</div>
```

and this is the working plunkr that I've made

http://plnkr.co/edit/C9AEuT0p1rpFoCGpIkHz?p=preview